# How to determine specific successRedirect in node js using express?

Tags: node.js, passport-local, passport.js

I have a question about successRedirecting in passport.authenticate.
I'm using passport.js and local strategy in nodejs and express for user login and trying to make specific successRedirect route.

For example, if I log in with user id: gpaul(pretended to be successed logging in), then successRedirect route is wanted to be '?channel=gpaul'.

I made the code like below

```
var data_1 = {email:''};
app.post('/login',
  function (req,res,next){
    req.flash("email");
    data_1.email = req.body.email;
    console.log(data_1.email);
    next();
  }, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : ('/status.html?channel='+ data_1.email),
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
  })
);
```

After implementing above code, the address comes out with blank ,
localhost:4000/?channel=
How can I put that data_1.email into successRedirect?

Does anybody have any ideas for that...?
Please help me out here..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Custom Callback](http://passportjs.org/docs) :

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
  return res.redirect('/status.html?channel='+ req.body.email);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

In this implementation, callback has access to the `req` and `res` objects through closure. Therefore, `email` will not be empty (unlike your implementation)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. :)

Comment: Can you help me out one more?? if you are not busy?

Comment: sure i can. Tell me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215663/redirecting-home-routes-in-node-js-using-express  Here is my another question I posted.. app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.redirect('/login');
});   doesn't redirect.. :'(

Comment: sorry my post is messy..:'(

Comment: Hey i just saw your post. Your code looks fine to me. Still i have suggested another aproach in my comment

Comment: Thanks I saw it, I think I know the problem, it is because of "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); because in the public folder, there is index.html so it keeps going to index.html..
But I'll try your suggestion first!! Thank you for helping me out I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry to bother you again.. I have a question from above post. If I want to take partial string from req.body.email, for example, from 'paul@example.com', I want to take just paul, then what should I write for the code?

Comment: Nvm, I figured out by using lastIndexOf("@")! :) Thanks